# Using MediaPlayer with OpenTK

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, opentk

I've seen examples on `Android` where a video is played with a `MediaPlayer` and each frame content is sent as a OES Texture External to a shader using the native Khronos `OpenGL ES 2.0` functionalities.

Is this possible to achieve the same result using `OpenTK`? And more simply, is `OpenTK` suitable for applying effects to a video on `Android`, versus GLES?